# How to sequentially/synchronously make API calls - EMFILE error

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios

I am trying to populate a database with data received from GET requests. Each request returns 500 items, which in turn makes 500 POSTs to the database. There are 686 GET requests to be made. The problem I am having is after the third GET, I start receiving `Error: connect EMFILE` and ended up with only ~1700 items in the database.

How would I make these API calls sequentially/synchronously to avoid this?

```js
function getProducts(myUrl) {
    axios.get(myUrl, { httpsAgent: agent })
        .then(res => {
            res.data.products.forEach(product => {
                var product = {
                    'values': {
                        '2': product.name,
                        '3': product.display_price,
                        '4': product.slug
                    }
                };
                postProduct(product);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}

function postProduct(product) {
    axios.post(huburl, product)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 686; i++) {
    var pagedUrl = url + '&page=' + i;
    console.log(pagedUrl);
    getProducts(pagedUrl);
}
```

Comment: switch to the async/await pattern and then you just need to await getProducts in your loop and you should be fine.

Comment: I am using AWS cloud 9 and their version of node does not support async I believe

Comment: You should double check, that makes your life a lot easier. What version of node is it?

Comment: @AdamH node -v returns v6.13.0... I just tried to install v10.8.0 via `nvm` and it says now using that version but still receiving syntax error when using `async`

Comment: Whats the syntax error?

Comment: Ok I fixed it, did `nvm use 10.8.0` and am able to run program. Now i need to look up how to use this pattern you mentioned.

Comment: Very simple, ill create a quick sample for you using your current code as a base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple conversion to async/await that I said I would post in the comments.

```js
async function getProducts(myUrl) {
  try {
    let res = await axios.get(myUrl, {
      httpsAgent: agent
    });
    res.data.products.forEach(product => {
      var product = {
        'values': {
          '2': product.name,
          '3': product.display_price,
          '4': product.slug
        }
      };

      await postProduct(product);

    });

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

async function postProduct(product) {
  try {
    let res = await axios.post(huburl, product);
    console.log(res.data);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 686; i++) {
  var pagedUrl = url + '&page=' + i;
  console.log(pagedUrl);
  await getProducts(pagedUrl);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error on line `await postProduct(product` is that a module I have to require? `parsing error unexpected token postProduct`

Comment: postProduct is your function, you should have to require anything. Might be a simple syntax error, ill have to double check.

Comment: Moved `async` into the arrow function inside `forEach` and syntax error went away

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound right. I'm not sure what an arrow function is. Is it working now?

Comment: Yes, it is just an anonymous function. Since the `await` must be inside an `async` function, I put `res.data.products.forEach(async product => ....)` and it worked. I was able to populate my table, well, at least 5 calls as a test, with 2500 items no problem. Thanks !!

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. Glad I could help.